# Xamarin, Spinner SharedPreferences Error?

Tags: xamarin, sharedpreferences

```
public class RD_OSBG : Fragment
{
    Spinner _BG_Position;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Test", FileCreationMode.Private);
        _BG_Position.SetSelection(prefs.GetInt("Test_Data", 0));

        // Create your fragment here
    }


    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View _RD_OSBG = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RD_OSBG_Layout, container, false);

        _BG_Position = (Spinner)_RD_OSBG.FindViewById(Resource.Id._BG_Position);
        ArrayList _BG_Position_Contents = new ArrayList { "Bow", "Stern" };
        _BG_Position.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this.Activity, Resource.Layout.Custom_Spinner, Resource.Id._Custom_Spinner_Text, _BG_Position_Contents);

        ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Test", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();


        _BG_Position.ItemSelected += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch(e.Position)
            {
                case 1:
                    Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "Stern", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    //_SaveSharedPreferences("Test", "Stern");
                    editor.PutInt("Test_Data", e.Position);
                    editor.Commit();
                    break;
            }

        };

      return _RD_OSBG;
    }
```

Error : Java.Lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

The current state is the same as we see in the code

And the error is the error below.
The part where the error occurs is as follows.
===> _BG_Position.SetSelection(prefs.GetInt("Test_Data", 0));

How can I save the Spinner's modified value in ISharedPreferences?

Comment: Do not delete and report the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50919166/xamarin-spinner-switch-seekbar-sharedpreference

Comment: @SushiHangover Without an answer to the question, I thought about it myself and asked about the error. I am sorry for my mistake.